# ASP.NET Core App Won't redirect user to login page after failing authorization, instead returns 404

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, authorization, identity

So I'm creating a small app for my work
I'm using .net 7, Asp.Net Core, Identity, and for authorization I'm using cookies
All my Login, Register and Logout pages located in Area, so the adress for those pages is something like Identity/Account/Login
Here all my program.cs file with all configuration

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Identity/Account/Logout";
        options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
        {
            IsEssential = true
        };
    });

builder.Services.AddAuthorization();

builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityDbContext>();

Dependencies.ConfigureServices(builder.Configuration, builder.Services);

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 4;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseCookiePolicy();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Orders}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();`



app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();
```

So my Login page work just fine when i try to access it by myself, but it have this contorller with`[Authorize]` attribute, and I expect it to redirect user to Login page if auth is failed, but instead, it returns me
No web page found for web adress https://localhost:7294/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
HTTP ERROR 404
I've tried changing login path in configuration, I've tried creating my custom attributes, but it's no use.
I'm really frustrated and think that is answer is just on the surfaces but I can't see it

Comment: The issue is with the route.  The authorization login does allow the path to be read.  When you remove the authorize it works.  See https://www.cofoundry.org/docs/framework/roles-and-permissions/authorizing-routes

Comment: @jdweng ok i see but the problem is that i want to have that attribute, and i want user to be redirected to login page. Alsow what do you mean by "The authorization login does allow the path to be read"?

Comment: Your routes are like a file system where different folders have different permission.  Some users can access a folder while others cannot.

Comment: @jdweng but still why i can access login page directly, but redirection from Authorization attribute won't do

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for me was to delete my pages with Login, Register and Logout, and everything associated with Identity configuration from my program.cs file, and scaffold Identity from scratch

This is the link that i found usefull:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio